# filtering a data frame by a varying number of logical columns

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I have a problem I'm sure has an elegant solution I haven't been able to find.

I have a function that creates a dataframe with a varying set of logical vectors. At the end of the function I'd like to combine all the existing logical vectors. The potential names are known, but there are enough that the various permutations with if statements are unworkable.

For example, the two data tables below. The potential logical vectors are "night", "pet", "rising", and from 1 to 3 of them will exist. I'd like code that can reliably combine whichever of the logical vectors exist.

I got as far as coming up with a list of the column numbers that match the names of the potential columns, but couldn't bring it home

Hopefully that was clear, thanks for the help

```
df1 <- structure(list(hour = structure(c(1123624800, 1123628400, 1123632000, 
1123635600, 1123639200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    night = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), pet = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), .Names = c("hour", "night", "pet"
), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(hour = structure(c(1123624800, 1123628400, 1123632000, 
1123635600, 1123639200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    night = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), pet = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), rising = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE)), .Names = c("hour", "night", "pet", "rising"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")


filters <- c("rising", "pet", "night")
match(filters, names(df))[!is.na(match(filters, names(df)))]
```

If I were to write out explicitly what I'd like the code to do:

```
return(df1[df1$night & df1$pet, ]) 
return(df2[df2$night & df2$pet $ df2$rising, ])
```

EDIT: I'm going to rewrite this to hopefully be more clear.
I have a dataframe with up to three logical vectors containing flags for various data quality filters. For example, the names of the three potential vectors are "night", "pet", "rising". The data frame will have some combination of from 1 to 3 of these vectors. Sometimes it will have "pet" and "night", or "night" and "rising", or "pet" and "rising", or all three....

I'd like to return the records where all of the *existing* logical vectors are true. The problem is that I will not know beforehand which of the vectors exist (this depends on the options in the function call), so I'd like to code to be able to handle all of the various combinations. Something like:

```
check which logical vectors exist
return(df[(all existing vectors are true), ]
```

If I just try

```
return(df[df$rising & df$pet $ df$night, ])
```

The code will fail whenever one of those columns is missing, so I need a more robust way to accomplish this.

Hopefully this is clearer! Generally if I can't articulate the problem it means I'm doing something stupid...

Comment: Assuming the second `structure` is, say, `df2`, you want to build a new `data.frame` that combines all the values from the matching columns in the two other data frames (if so, what do want done with the `NA`'s that may result? Or, do you want a named list of combined vectors? A sample of what you would like as a result would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

```
df2[Reduce(`&`, df2[sapply(df2, is.logical)]),]
```

will return rows for which all logical columns are `TRUE`.  You can also use the `apply` method described at the end.

---

You can achieve your objective with `Reduce` and `&`:

```
df1[Reduce(`&`, df1[-1]),]
#                  hour night  pet
# 3 2005-08-10 00:00:00  TRUE TRUE
# 4 2005-08-10 01:00:00  TRUE TRUE
# 5 2005-08-10 02:00:00  TRUE TRUE
```

Above we excluded the first column with `-1`.  Below we use the list of columns you defined in `filters`:

```
df2[Reduce(`&`, df2[filters]),]
#                  hour night  pet rising
# 4 2005-08-10 01:00:00  TRUE TRUE   TRUE
```

`Reduce` iteratively applies `&` to pairs of elements in its second argument (the columns in the data frame).

Alternatively, you can use `apply`:

```
df2[apply(df2[filters], 1, all),]
df1[apply(df1[-1], 1, all),]
```

Comment: The first solution (excluding the first column) works, but I was unable to get the second to work. However, since this is going to be a function that users are calling I'm hoping for a more robust way to identify the existing columns. I've edited my question to be more clear. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @IcebergSlim, can you provide more clarity on what you mean by the second one not working?  How does it fail?  Are you sure that `df2` and `filters` variables you are using are exactly as in your `dput`s in your question?  I would recommend you clear your workspace and re-create `df2` and `filter`.

Comment: @IcebergSlim, see updated answer to address your edit.

Comment: Thanks, that works. If the df the user passes to the function has logicals in it already that could be a problem, but I'll stick a check for that at the top of the function. Thanks again,