# Helping Reduce handle single column arguments

Tags: r

In followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645491/filtering-a-data-frame-by-a-varying-number-of-logical-columns), I am having some trouble with the Reduce function. I am using it to combine logical vectors in a dataframe and return the records where all logicals are true:

```
testdf <- structure(list(idx = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), logical.1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), logical.2 = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE)), .Names = c("idx", "logical.1", "logical.2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

Reduce('&',testdf[,2:3],)
```

so far so good. The problem is that if there is only a single logical vector Reduce returns a single false value

```
Reduce('&',testdf[,2],)
```

What I'd like it to do in the case of a single logical vector is return the records where that vector is True, essentially

```
testdf[testdf$logical.1, ]
```

This could be done with a little coding before the Reduce call, but I'm wondering if there isn't an elegant solution in the arguments to Reduce? 
Thanks

EDIT: don't know how to mark it as answered, since answer came in a comment, but Frank nailed it. Done and done.

Comment: `Reduce('&',testdf[,2,drop=FALSE],)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it:

```
Reduce('&',testdf[,2,drop=FALSE],)
```

I think this works because the second argument to `Reduce` is now a list, not a vector.

---

If you are making a function...

```
allCols <- function(DF,cols){
  Reduce('&',testdf[,cols,drop=FALSE],)
}

# testing
allCols(testdf,2)
allCols(testdf,2:3)
```